# How can I get my for each loop to print once for each number in the array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

assignment:
Write a program that reads in integers between 1 and 100 from the user and counts the
occurrences of each number. The user input ends when they enter a 0.
You must use an enhanced for-loop to solve this problem.
If a number occurs more than 1 time use the plural word “times” instead of “time”. Do not display numbers that were not entered.

I know and understand why my code's current output below appears with duplicates.  The print logic is inside the for-each loop code block.  If I close the code block I am no longer able to use the variables I initialized inside the loop.  I have tried everything I can think of. Any suggestions would be appreciated

current output:
- 1 occurs 1 time,
- 1 occurs 2 times 
- 2 occurs 1 time 
- 2 occurs 2 times
- 3 occurs 1 time
- 3 occurs 2 times

needed output:
- 1 occurs 2 times 
- 2 occurs 2 times 
- 3 occurs 2 times

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[10];

    System.out.print("Enter Integers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
        if (numbers[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    enhancedLoop(numbers);
    }

    private static void enhancedLoop(int[] numbers) {
        int[] counts = new int[101];

        for (int value : numbers) {
            counts[value]++;

            if (value > 0)
                 if (counts[value]> 1)
                     System.out.println(value + " occurs " + counts[value]+ " times");
                 else
                     System.out.println(value + " occurs " + counts[value] + " time");

        }
```

}

Comment: it is quite messy my apologies, my first SO post and have some sick crying kids. I appreciate you taking the time to look at it still .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are only available in the block in which they are declared. Move the output after the for loop and iterate over counts to display the values:

```
for (int i = 0, c = counts.length; i < c; ++i) {
    if (counts[i] > 0) {
        if (counts[i] > 1) {
            System.out.println(value + " occurs " + counts[i]+ " times");
        } else {
            System.out.println(value + " occurs " + counts[i]+ " time");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] numbers = new int[10];

    System.out.print("Enter Integers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
        if (numbers[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    enhancedLoop(numbers);


}

private static void enhancedLoop(int[] numbers) {
    int[] counts = new int[101];

    for (int value : numbers) {
        counts[value]++;

        if (value > 0)
            if (counts[value]> 1)
                System.out.println(value + " occurs " + counts[value]+ " times");

            else
                System.out.println(value + " occurs " + counts[value] + " time");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this effectively using the below steps:

(1) **Identify the unique numbers first**

(2) **Find the number of times each unique number occurs**

So, you need to change your `enhancedLoop(int[] numbers)` method as shown below to achieve the result:

```
private static void enhancedLoop(int[] numbers) {

  //convert the array to a list to make computations easier by using streams
  List<Integer> numbersList = Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

  //Get the unique numbers in the list
  List<Integer> uniqueNumbers = numbersList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

  //Now find out number of times each each unique number occured
  for(int number : uniqueNumbers) {
      long times = numbersList.stream().filter(num -> num == number).count();
      System.out.println(number+" occurs "+times);
    }
 }
```

Comment: If it helps, great, you can accept/upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

lets try to do this without lamdas, using simply a hashmap instead of arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int tmp=0;
        System.out.print("Enter Integers:");

        //read a maximum of 10 int
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tmp = in.nextInt();

            //if we read a 0 we quit
            if (tmp == 0) {
                break;
            }

            //if we already saw the number we up the counter
            if(numbers.containsKey(tmp)){
                numbers.put(tmp, numbers.get(tmp)+1);
            }else{
                //otherwise we just add the new int
                numbers.put(tmp, 1);
            }
        }

        //call the print loop
        enhancedLoop(numbers);
    }

    private static void enhancedLoop(HashMap<Integer, Integer> numbers) {
        //you print what you counted
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : numbers.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " occurs " + entry.getValue() + " time");

        if (entry.getValue()>1)
            System.out.print("s");

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Tahar for the response, was only using arrays sinc the assignment calls for it:
Write a program that reads in an array of integers between 1 and 100 from the user and counts the
occurrences of each number. The user input ends when they enter a 0.
You must use an enhanced for-loop to solve this problem.